# Can we have two endpoints having same name but different address in a configuration file

Tags: .net, wcf

Can we have two endpoints having same name but different address in a configuration file

For example, whether below code is correct?

```
<*endpoint* name="**WSHttpBinding_ICalcService**"
          address="**net.pipe://myService/Request.svc/Switch/MyDataService**" 
          binding="**wsHttpBinding**" 
          bindingConfiguration="**WSHttpBinding_ICalcService**" 
          contract="**ServiceReference1.ICalcService**">
<*endpoint* name="**WSHttpBinding_ICalcService**"
          address="**net.pipe://myService/Response.svc/Switch/MyDataService**" 
          binding="**wsHttpBinding**" 
          bindingConfiguration="**WSHttpBinding_ICalcService**" 
          contract="**ServiceReference1.ICalcService**">
```

Above configuration is same, only addresses are different. Is it possible? It seems it is not possible. But wanted to confirm?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `netNamedPipeBinding` since you're using `net.pipe`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes name has to be unique if you are specifying it. It is an optional attribute check the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731320.aspx) Here is the explanation for name attribute.

> Optional attribute. A string that specifies the name the service endpoint. The default value is the concatenation of the binding name and the contract description name. Services may have multiple endpoints, so the endpoint’s name attribute is distinct from the name of the service.